# how do I know which class & function it's calling?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Ruby and Ruby on Rails. Have Java, C#, NodeJS background. I will have to work on Rails application. When reading the code, all of the sudden I see it calls a function from some class. Lets say

```
class HelloWorld < ApplicationController
   before_action :get_data

   def get_data
      @data = SomeClass.SomeMethod(AAA: :BBB)
   end
end
```

As coming from C# / Java background I don't understand where is that SomeClass and where is that SomeMethod (SomeClass is defined in 5 places).

It could be a newbie question. But it helps other people who comes from other languages.

Comment: There is a good list of debugging tricks using puts in this blogpost by Aaron patterson https://tenderlovemaking.com/2016/02/05/i-am-a-puts-debuggerer.html

Comment: Within Rails the rule of thumb is it's in `some_class.rb` stored somewhere, but many Ruby tools exist to find out for sure: `puts SomeClass.method(:SomeMethod).source_location` is usually the most precise.

Comment: You can also install ruby ctags in your editor (I do it with sublime, pretty sure it's there in others as well). This lets you mouse over the method call to see where it's defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to find method location is to use [Method#source_location](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Method.html#method-i-source_location). In your case you need to do this:

```
SomeClass.method(:SomeMethod).source_location
```

it will give you file path and line number where this method is defined